What kind of repetition-specific literary device is being used in this quote? (e.g. anaphora, epistrophe, diacope, etc.)
I'm analysing the below quote from The Love Song of J. Alfred Prufrock:
"To prepare a face to meet the faces that you meet"
I want to identify the specific kind of repetition that's being used here, but none of the ones I know seem to fit. Does anyone have any ideas as to what it might be?

There are numerous figures of repetition that address the repetition of words. Have you checked them all?

@henryflower Thanks for the helpful list! I'd heard of most of them, but a few were unfamiliar - one of which being 'repotia' which I think fits based off of the description. I could have interpreted it wrong though.
